# React is updating both child component when data linked to one child is changing

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have 2 component

1. Shape
2. video

And they are in 1 route  **./home**

And i have context for **./home** route as

```
<Router>
  <div >
    <PContext>
      <Route exact path="/" component={home} />
    </PContext>
  </div>
</Router>
```

Now in home i have

```
...
function Home() {
  
    useEffect( ()=>{
        console.log('Rendered PDetect')
    })
    
    return (
        <div>
                <Video/>
                <Shape/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

And i have function in Video child ( to detect aspect ratio ) and it will update the value of aspect ratio in variable in **PContext** and shape component will use that value and display it.

```
...
const Shape = () => {

    const { ratio }  = useContext(PDataContext)

    console.log("ratio",ratio)
    useEffect( ()=>{
        console.log('Rendered Shape')
    })
      
    return (
       <span className="shape_circle" >1</span>
    )
}

export default Shape
```

And context file is

```
...  
export const PDataContext = createContext()

const PContext = ( props ) => {

   const [ ratio , setSetRatio ] = useState([])
  
  const gotRatio = r => {
    setSetRatio(r[0].key)
  }

  return(<PoseDataContext.Provider value={{
            gotRatio,
            ratio}}>
                {props.children}
        </PoseDataContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default PoseContext
```

My problem is that Video child use **gotRatio** function and update the value of ratio and shape component use ratio value to display it. But when **gotRatio** function update it re-render both Shape and Video component so Video start from 0sec again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the consumers will update its expected as of [ReactJS Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider)

> All consumers that are descendants of a Provider will re-render whenever the Provider’s `value` prop changes. The propagation from Provider to its descendant consumers (including `.contextType` and `useContext`) is not subject to the `shouldComponentUpdate` method, so the consumer is updated even when an ancestor component skips an update.

Comment: Any solution to this ? other than using redux ?

Comment: well, i faced similar issue and i had to split the context in two (as the two components were using different properties it worked). But, ur using same property, so no better idea than using  state (`redux` as u prefer)